# Prism Unity background view

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, unity-container, prism

I'm trying to work with unity prism and WPF. What I've done so far is an application that look for module in directory and load it on demand. Everything works pretty well. I can navigate between my module using requestnavigate.

But I'm facing a problem and I can't find any good documentation on this.
I have some module who need to continue the execution (run in background). For example, I have a VOIP module and mediaplayer module who need to continue the execution while I'm navigate to another module. Is it possible to use a requestnavigate and maybe thread the previous view/viewmodel until it become the current view ?

Answer (score 0):

we can run it in separate thread

```
 // Subscribe to Composite Presentation Events
    var eventAggregator = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IEventAggregator>();
    var navigationCompletedEvent = eventAggregator.GetEvent<NavigationCompletedEvent>();
    navigationCompletedEvent.Subscribe(OnNavigationCompleted, ThreadOption.UIThread);
```

Events can be subscribed in separate thread

```
subscriptionToken = AddedEvent.Subscribe(AddedEventHandler, 
                               ThreadOption.UIThread, false, erFilter);
```

[View-Switching-Applications-with-Prism](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165370/Creating-View-Switching-Applications-with-Prism)

[PRISM App](http://www.global-webnet.com/blogengine/post/2009/07/31/Does-PRISM-have-a-performance-issue.aspx)

[Prism-WPF-standalone-and-interaction-modules](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/628914/Prism-WPF-standalone-and-interaction-modules-in-VS)

Comment: I didn't get the answer :S . The eventAggregator able me to call a function from another module. So basically what you are expaining. is to subscribe to an event when the navigation is performed from another view. But i would like to thread the viewModel who is not currently used for the active view. I have so much difficulties. To understand the goal of the Uithread in this case. I try also to understand the role of the Dispatcher in WPF application who probably abble me to run the Viewmodel in different thread.